# Only return hits with x occurences with like statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql like statement:

```
Select * FROM table WHERE content LIKE '%word%'
```

This will return all rows where 'word' is found in column content. But is it possible to add a parameter to this statement so that I only return rows where "word" is found two (or three, or four, or five....) times.

Comment: `like '%word%word%word%'` ?

Comment: @thebjorn I think that it is very smart solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stealing @thebjorn's comment but making it more general:

```
$theword = "word"; // apply appropriate escaping, especially with user input
                   // you will also need to manually escape % and _
$count = 4;
$like_condition = str_repeat("%".$theword,$count)."%";

$query = "select * from table where content like '".$like_condition."'";
```

Comment: :) It is not stealing, it is showing the way of best implementation in PHP. +1

Comment: Great, this will really help me! Thank's!

Comment: Steal away :-)  (I upvoted you 'cause I thought it was such a good answer *wink*)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with Procedural function like that:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION substrCount(s VARCHAR(255), ss VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
  BEGIN
  DECLARE count TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE offset TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET s = NULL;

  SET count = 0;
  SET offset = 1;

  REPEAT
  IF NOT ISNULL(s) AND offset > 0 THEN
  SET offset = LOCATE(ss, s, offset);
  IF offset > 0 THEN
  SET count = count + 1;
  SET offset = offset + 1;
  END IF;
  END IF;
  UNTIL ISNULL(s) OR offset = 0 END REPEAT;

  RETURN count;
  END;
```

and you can call it like that

```
 SELECT substrCount('word kkhword word jfdj word', 'word') as `counts`; //-- Returns 4
```

[**WATCH DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/227130/3)